# WebBluetooth Failing a Write Characteristic on Windows but not OSX

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm trying to send a sample hex string to a BLE device via web bluetooth.

This string is sending perfectly fine on OSX, but when I attempt to send it on windows I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: GATT operation failed for unknown reason.
```

Here is the code I'm using to send the string and convert it:

```
        event.target.writeValue(str2ab(":100000000C9434000C943E000C943E000C943E0082*"));
```

Here is my str2ab function:

```
 function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same problems on Windows also, you aren't alone!

Comment: @EL45 I've narrowed the problem down to being that on Windows you can only send 20 bytes at a time! I'll rewrite the way I'm sending data and post it as a solution.

Comment: @EL45 I just posted a fix!

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like for windows you have a 20 byte limit.

To correct the issue I'm using a write buffer and recursively going over it until all the bites have been written. Here is the code.

```
function writeBuffer(string) {
  writeOut(string, 0);
}

function writeOut(string, start) {
  if(start >= string.length) return;
  myCharacteristic.writeValue(str2ab(string.substring(start, (start+20)))).then(foo => {
    writeOut(string, (start+20));
  });
}
```

Comment: Where did you find that Windows has a 20 byte limit?